# `curl -i -X HEAD 'https://alice_yandex-1-d6981971.deta.app/'` command returns `curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`

Tags: windows, curl, cmd

`curl -i -X HEAD 'https://alice_yandex-1-d6981971.deta.app/'` command in cmd returns `curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`.
I don't know a reason.

I tried to find some information about this and everywhere it is written that this is due to invalid characters. But there are no such characters in URL

Answer (score 0):

The command you gave works for me. Could it be you have one of the curl environment variables like `HTTPS_PROXY` incorrectly set? You can check if this command works:

```
env -i curl -i -X HEAD 'https://alice_yandex-1-d6981971.deta.app/'
```

Then some environment variable is messing you up.